# Querying with relationship not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to grab an `InvoiceDetails` record and the matching `Product` record via the product foreign key.

This isn't working:

```
$r = InvoiceDetail::with('products')->find(52184)->toArray();
```

The 2 database calls are

```
SELECT * FROM `invoice_details` WHERE `id` = '52184' LIMIT 1    
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` in ('0')
```

Where am I going wrong?

Table Structure of invoice details:

```
Schema::create('invoice_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('invoice_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('quantity');
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->foreign('invoice_id')->references('id')->on('invoices')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

});
```

Table structure for Products:

```
Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
});
```

Products Model:

```
class Product extends \Eloquent 
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('InvoiceDetail');
    }

}
```

Invoice Details Model:

```
class InvoiceDetail extends \Eloquent
{
    public function details()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Invoice');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Product');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer (there is 2 hours of my life I'm never getting back) I had to manually add the fk and pk. So in my InvoiceDetails model it should have looked like this

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Product', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your relationships are weird. (Okay, that wasn't really any longer.)

Assuming that an Invoice can belong to many Products (with specific details about each such as quantity), and that a Product can belong to many Invoices, you have a [classic pivot table scenario](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many). In which case, you're doing extra work and making life more difficult for yourself than it has to be.

If that's the case, there are a few steps you can take to reduce your code and make life easier:

1. **Remove the `InvoiceDetails` model.** Laravel can handle pivot tables on its own pretty well. So unless you have something really custom that you need the pivot table model to handle, you don't need it.
2. **Update your `Product` model.** You have a `products()` method in the Product model. That doesn't really make any sense. Don't products belong to *invoices*? Let's fix that.

   ```
   class Product extends Eloquent
   {
       public function invoices()
       {
           return $this->belongsToMany('Invoice', 'invoice_details', 'product_id', 'invoice_id');
       }
   }
   ```

   The additional parameters indicate the pivot table name, the column name for the Product model identifier, and the column name for the Invoice model identifier, respectively.
3. **Update your `Invoice` model.** You didn't paste it here, but I'll assume it has a relationship for invoice details. If not, well, oops! Because an invoice can belong to many products, essentially the inverse of the products relationship we just defined, it's defined it pretty much the exact same way.

   ```
   class Invoice extends Eloquent
   {
       public function products()
       {
           return $this->belongsToMany('Product', 'invoice_details', 'invoice_id', 'product_id');
       }
   }
   ```

You now have a many-to-many relationship between Products and Invoices, that is retrieved using intuitive relationship methods! Huzzah.

#### Hey wait, where's my quantity?

You'll have to figure that one out [on your own](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables). :)

Comment: I think I wasn't clear. The invoice table has a one to many relationship with the invoice_details table. So the invoice table holds things like customer, date, etc. The invoice_details table holds all the line items so product_id, the quantity of that product etc.

Comment: You don't need a hasMany relationship from Invoice to InvoiceDetails, because all InvoiceDetails does is map an invoice to a product (with a little meta data like quantity). If it acts like a pivot table, treat it like one. :)

Comment: This is a classic 1 to many relationship. There are usually many ItemDetails for each invoice. They contain the quantity, what product, price that the customer is getting billed for at the time of the invoice creation, etc.

Comment: It's a one to many relationship because you've defined it as such, which, in my opinion, is more work than it needs to be. But suit yourself, it's your app, not mine. :)